# wshttpbinding is only for .net clients?

Tags: java, wcf, wshttpbinding

Is the **wsHttpBinding** only for **.NET clients**?

Because in wsHttpBinding default security is enabled, so data transferred with encryption.
So how can non-.NET clients (like **java or php**) consume such WCF services?

Answer (score 1):

The default Message security for WsHttpBinding is set to "Windows", I believe. This may well be because this will make security work out of the box, at least for a WCF service and client.

If you need to be interoperable, it's easy to change this though. You can set it to any one of these:

- Windows (the default)
- None
- UserName
- Certificate
- IssuedToken

See the ["message, of wsHttpBinding" MSDN page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731346.aspx) for more details. To test communication with your Java or PHP client you could temporarily disable security:

```xml
<wsHttpBinding>
  <binding>
    <security mode="Message">
      <!-- Not recommended! Use only for testing. -->
      <message clientCredentialType="None" />
    </security>
  </binding>
</wsHttpBinding>
```

After you got things working you could switch to -for example- using certificates, depending on what your non-WCF side supports.

Answer (score 1):

As Jeroen says by default wsHttpBinding defaults to message security and windows credentials

For non-Windows clients you will need to change the authentication mode. However, if you stay with message security you also need any consuming toolkit to have an implementation of WS-Security (and WS-Trust / WS-SecureConversation).

What features of wsHttpBinding are you using that means basicHttpBinding isn't appropriate? BasicHttpBinding is a simpler binding to get working in interop scenarios